# NuGet restore unable to connect & find version of package

Tags: nexus, nuget-package-restore, sonatype

When trying NuGet restore sometimes we get this Warning Message followed by Unable to find version,

```
cmd>NuGet restore My.sln -NoCache 
WARNING: Unable to connect to the remote server
WARNING: Unable to connect to the remote server
Unable to find version '2.0.3930.0' of package 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml'.
Unable to find version '4.157.1212.0' of package 'Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient'.
```

The above packages are available in the repository. This is an intermittent issue & can't be reproduce on demand.

The nexus repository is up and running. No issues found in the nexus logs.

Comment: "WARNING: Unable to connect to the remote server"  ... from this it sounds like nuget can't connect to Nexus at all.  Check for network problems.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add that point. Network is fine, some artifact restore works fine in the same time.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? It might help me as I'm getting a similar issue.

Comment: Nope, not yet. I haven't seen this error in recent time.